# How to disable input but not get the greyed out tone on the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

I am disabling the input. But I would like the text to still be clear and readable. Right now its greyed out, as is the intention I suppose. Is this something I have to do with CSS or can it be achieved with javascript/jquery? The snippet version got better readability then my actual input.
My Code:

```js
  jQuery('#displayName').val("sampleText");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="displayName" style="margin-right:15px;">Namn</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayName" disabled value="">
</div>
```

Comment: readonly or do not make it an input

Comment: I am such an idot. ofcourse.`readonly`. totally forgot. @itay ´s solution looks visually better. I get the grey background of the input when `readonly`. Thanks to both of you. I will combine the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style it as you like using the `:disabled` selector:

```js
jQuery('#displayName').val("sampleText");
```

```css
#displayName:disabled {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="displayName" style="margin-right:15px;">Namn</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayName" disabled value="">
</div>
```

Comment: I will definitly add this one to my memory bank.Thanks!

Comment: I want to accept the answer, but it wont let me for about 8min, will do it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use styles then you can use the **readonly** attribute.

A javascript solution is

```
node.onfocus = function(){node.blur();};
```